# Программа нахождения суммы двух чисел в строке

Tags: c, алгоритм

Здравствуйте. Нужна помощь по написанию программы на си:
Есть один входной файл input.txt, в котором записана последовательность строк и в каждой строке есть два целых неотрицательных числа. Задача одна- сформировать выходной файл output.txt любым способом, в каждой строке которого будет содержаться результат сложения этих двух чисел. Учитывать, что порядок следования строк в input.txt должен соответствовать output.txt файлу.

Comment: Помощью вы называете написание за вас?

Comment: Нет, просто хотелось бы получить примерную идею реализации программы

Comment: Открываете файл, читаете построчно, преобразовываете строки в числа, складываете и пишете в другой файл.

Comment: [man fgets](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets), [man sscanf](https://linux.die.net/man/3/sscanf) в помощь

Comment: @Вячеслав161 Поставьте себя на место компьютера. Какие действия вы бы делали?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
FILE * input = fopen("input.txt","rt");
FILE * output = fopen("output.tx","wt");

int i, j;

while(fscanf(input,"%d %d",&i,&j) == 2)
{
    fprintf(output,"%d\n",i+j);
}

fclose(input);
fclose(output);
```